# Multiple caches in Memcached

Tags: java, caching, memcached

I am migrating caches **from EhCache to Memcached**. With only 1 Memcached instance, is there a way to have multiple caches (as in EhCache)?

For example, I want to have a "Users" cache, a "Products" cache, etc... The main reason for that is to be able to monitor and configure each cache separately, and be able to clear them separately too.

Comment: What memcached client are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, this sort of behavior is achieved in memcached via namespacing.  Within a single memcached instance, one maintains multiple namespaces, each of which represents a different cache.  However, memcached doesn't natively support namespaces - instead, memcached namespaces are emulated by prefixing keys with a namespace identifier (e.g., `memcachedClient.get('products.top10')`).  Some memcached clients, like [the Python GAE memcached client](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_set), abstract this behavior for you.  However, xmemcached does not, as far as I can tell.

You are left with two options.

- Manually prefix each key you work with.
- Write a thin wrapper around `XMemcachedClient` with two changes: it has a `String namespace` member that serves as the prefix value, and it overrides [`get0()`](https://github.com/killme2008/xmemcached/blob/master/src/main/java/net/rubyeye/xmemcached/XMemcachedClient.java#L952) to apply that prefix.  This is a bit dangerous as it relies on the current XMemcached implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I will indeed write a custom service handling cache namespaces around XMemcachedClient (not overriding the class, rather "Facade" design pattern)